# Filling some region with colour, and the rest of the image as black

Tags: matlab, colors, polygon, fill, region

I have drawn some polygon on an image after using `imshow` and `hold on`, and filled it with `white` as follows:

```
fill(x(k),y(k),[1 1 1])
```

How can I make the rest of the image `black` while keeping the polygon `white`? In other words, how can I make a binary image, where the polygon is `white`, and the rest of the image is `black`? Provided that the polygon is a bit complex.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`roipoly`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html):

```
BW = roipoly( I, x(k), y(k) );
```

Where `I` is your input image (you only need it to get the desired output size of the binary maxk `BW`). `y` and `x` are the corners of your polygon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion. For `y`, I have entered my `ymax` value, and `x` my `xmin` value. And, `I` is my original image. But, when I ran the line you provided I got a black image. Maybe I'm missing something that I had to enter before `BW`?

Comment: @Simplicity `y` and `x` should be **vectors** of all x and y coordinates of the corners of your polygon. If your polygon has 3 corners (a triangle) then x and y should have 3 values (each).

Comment: I just swapped x(k) and y(k), such that, I wrote x(k) before y(k), and think that I got the desired result. Thanks